# Automatically Generate Documentation for commits in TortoiseSVN

Tags: windows, svn, documentation, tortoisesvn, documentation-generation

I want to find a way to generate documentation of a commit automatically.
We are using SVN and we all use TortoiseSVN as the client software.
(Most of the code is C++ and we are using windows)

It will be enough if we can extract the following commit related data at each commit,

- Revision number
- Log message
- Affected files (modified/added/erased..etc.) list
- the change ( could be hard to identify, but at least we can get old and new copies of the affected files at least )

and we need all these info in a single text file. ( a file for each commit )

Comment: Might want to start looking at post-commit hooks server-side.

Comment: Yah thats a way to do that, but we were thinking if there is a simpler way in tortoiseSVN.

Answer (score 0):

Use the log dialog (right-click, "`Show Log`").

Select all the revisions since your last release, then hit `Ctrl+C` or if you don't need the affected files hit `Ctrl+Shift+C`.
After that, you have all the info you need in the clipboard, ready to be pasted in whatever editor you like.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. But i want to automate this process. how to do that??

Comment: if you want to automate, use the command line client, not TSVN: svn log -v > logfile.txt

Comment: ya i decided to write a script ( in python ) for it. ill put it here after i hv completed it :) thank you :)